# How to check apache maven version 3.1.1 or newer is installed in a machine?

Tags: apache, maven-3

I am absolutely new to Java Enterprise Edition and can someone help me by providing the steps needed to check whether Apache maven version 3.1.1 or newer is installed in a machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by executing mvn -version.
if the command is not found, no version is installed correctly else there is an output of the maven version.

If you want to check it programatically you can write an java application which executes the mvn -version command and reads the result of the process.
(Search for java Runtime.getRuntime().exec )